Moving IIS to new server introduces networking issues on old and new server
Currently replacing some EoL servers including our web server.  The EoL server is a physical server that only functions as our web server.
The new server is running VMs under Hyper-V and I've set that up and the VM for the new web server, the virtual switch, etc.  Network connectivity is good and I have copied over all IIS content, settings etc.
I had thought if I performed the following steps, I could seamlessly cutover to the new server:

Rename current server SERVER-NAME to SERVER-NAME-OLD
Assign SERVER-NAME-OLD new IP address
Reboot SERVER-NAME-OLD
Log into SERVER-NAME-OLD, stop all IIS services
Rename new server SERVER-NAME-TEMP to SERVER-NAME
Assign SERVER-NAME IP config of SERVER-NAME-OLD
Reboot SERVER-NAME
Log into SERVER-NAME, ensure all services running correctly

However, the issue I run into is after this, BOTH servers have no network connectivity.  The old server has the dreaded "Unidentified network" message and the new one has the globe (no connectivity) icon.
I'm not sure what the issue could be, I have assigned a static IP to the old server and the old server's IP config to the new one.
I had thought maybe it had something to do with our firewall  (Sonicwall NSA 2600) and Address Objects but there are just IPs assigned to them, not MAC addresses or anything so everything should just work.
Is there a step I am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Are both servers in the same VLAN? If they're on the same physical host, are they assigned to the same vSwitch and do they have the same VLAN ID specified in the Hyper-V VM configuration? Are they able to ping their "default gateway"? Is the default gateway the same for both?

@u1686_grawity the old server is a physical server and the new one is a virtual server on a completely different physical Hyper-V server.  The default gateway is different as the web server needs access to outside the domain.

Are they still on the same network, though? Does the same VLAN extend from the old server's physical port to the new server's vSwitch port?

@u1686_grawity yes, they are on the same network in the same domain, the old server is a physical server that is just the web server.  The new server is a Hyper-V server and the new web server is a VM on it.  I am not using VLANs.  Hope that is clear, thx

Have you done basic network troubleshooting such as pinging the gateway in that network from the two machines? Consult your network administrators, as they are the ones who master such concepts. Limiting which machine can bind to an IP address is very important, so I do somehow expect your steps to fail like this in the end.

@LexLi turns out the web server needed to be directly connected to the firewall so I dropped a NIC from the Hyper-V SET Team and created a virtual switch for a single port, assigned it to the web server VM and connected that port to the firewall and now everything works as expected.  Should have known, thanks!
